# Apache server root access from Netbeans

Tags: apache2, root, netbeans

I get this error warning when I select to copy project files from source folder to another location (my apache root: /var/www/html/) "The directory must be accessible via your web server at URL `http://localhost/html/PhpProject2/`". This ends up giving an error on running the project. I want to be able to create netbeans projects in apache root and run them from netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run following command to, when you want to edit files. (This make file accessible/editable for all users)

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/`

## And to revert back, run following command (make file inaccessible/ to group and others)

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/`

`sudo chmod -R 644 /var/www/html/`

Comment: Thanks Sagar that was really helpful, in addition to your answer the following configuration also made it happen: "Under name and location settings: Source URL=/var/www/html/netbeans-project-name/, and under run configuration:  Project URL=http://localhost/netbeans-project-name/". this helped me. Most grateful Sagar